# Upgrade MSI and using Eleckey updateshield

Tags: windows-installer

I have made setup of my windows application I want to create autoupdates. For this I used ElecKey. for installation upgrades I create full patch so I create another MSI with same Upgrade code with new Product version and set RemovePreviousVersion to True. But I found the MSI is not replacing files even application is running still MSI is  installing application. What to do?

Comment: Where is the C# involved with this question?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a Visual Studio installer project, because RemovePreviousVersions is the term they use. So:

1. "Create full patch" isn't what you're doing, so using that description will confuse people. You're doing a major upgrade, an MSI that is both a full fresh install as well as automatically uninstalling the old product if there happens to be one already installed.
2. VS setup projects won't upgrade individual files unless you increment their file versions. Like every other update mechanism (patches, service packs, hot fixes etc) files are replaced only if the incoming file version is higher. So assuming your upgrade is otherwise working, increment the file versions of your versioned files, and if they don't have file versions then start using them.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367835(v=vs.85).aspx

3. An upgrade won't work unless the context is the same: An Everyone install will upgrade only an Everyone install, and a Just me install will upgrade only a Just me installed product. If you see two entries in Programs&Features it hasn't worked properly.